# Have visibility / sharing settings intentionally changed with Developer Story launch?

Tags: support, developer-story

With the launch of Developer Story, it looks like visibility settings have changed for migrated CVs. Is this intentional?

My old CV at `http://stackoverflow.com/cv/{slug}` was publicly visible (it's still in the Google cache), but now both `http://stackoverflow.com/cv/{slug}` and `http://stackoverflow.com/story/{slug}` are hidden, and in fact have different 404-style pages (the former is an old `/jobs` 404 page, the latter is the standard SO 404 with the code sample).

It says in the email about the Developer Story launch:

> You are receiving this email because you have a Stack Overflow CV.
>   We’ve migrated your CV to your Developer Story. **If your CV was visible
>   to employers, they’ll be able to see both the traditional view and the
>   new Developer Story view of your information.**

but I'm not sure the last sentence of this is true - I suppose it might be true for employers logged into whatever system they have, but it's certainly not true for anonymous browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your visibility settings were changed because while your Careers CV was set to public, you did not have your Careers account and Stack Overflow profiles linked together (some people did that for privacy reasons).  As a result, we set your Dev Story to private so you could make the decision if you wanted your Developer Story public or private.

If you want your Dev Story public, then you can easily fix this by going to Your Developer Story Preferences (either linked on your dev story page or on edit profile & settings) and changing the privacy settings on your Developer Story. Once you do this your story view and traditional view URLs should work.